# ¿Como activar en la barra de navegación el li de la página actual?

Tags: php, bootstrap, aplicación-web

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web en PHP y usando bootstrap y me ha surgido el siguiente problema.
Estoy usando el componente navBar para hacer la barra de navegación, el código HTML de la barra es el siguiente

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Este código lo tengo escrito en un fichero PHP llamado navegacion.php y lo incluyo mediante un require_once("navegacion.php") en todas las paginas en las que necesito la barra (Son bastantes y no me gustaría escribir el código en todas). Pero no sé como hacer para que en la barra aparezca como active el li de la página actual y no siempre el mismo li

Answer (score 1):

Con jquery podrias asi:

```
$(function() {
  var menues = $(".nav li"); 
      menues.click(function() {
      menues.removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

Guardas en una variable menus los li que hay en el nav.
Luego cuando das click al li lo que hace es sacarle la clase active a todos y luego le agrega la clase active al que le diste click

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He probado con el código jquery que me indicaste @Juan , pero no consigo que funcione, supongo que estoy haciendo algo mal pero no descubro el qué. He subido aquí los archivos que he creado (https://github.com/AllenPeter/navBarActive)